# Bose Soundsport Bluetooth headphones volume unusually low on Ubuntu 18 and 16

Tags: bluetooth, pulseaudio, alsa, headphones

I have been facing this problem for a couple years and have tried to fix it several times. Nothing in these posts seems to address the specific problem. This problem has been happening since Ubuntu 16 and Bose Soundsport 1, but I am now experiencing this issue on Ubuntu 18 and have a newer model of Bose Soundsport Free.

[Volume low even at maximum](https://askubuntu.com/questions/390734/volume-low-even-at-maximum)

[Ubuntu 18.04 bluetooth low volume](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1109570/ubuntu-18-04-bluetooth-low-volume)

The Bluetooth earbuds hook up seamlessly no issues there. They are extremely quiet like barely audible. When using these earbuds on my phone they are capable of getting loud enough to be uncomfortable and they have really nice audio clarity.

- If you check alsamixer all channels are up all the way.
- If you use pavucontrol to increase the volume in any combination of ways you get significant audio distortion, and the audio is really still not as loud as the buds produce when synced to android.
- If you switch from an A2DP profile to an HSP/HFP profile you get much worse nearly unusable distortion, making them unusable for video conference.

What are the next steps to take to improve the audio quality on this bluetooth device, even if it's a complex or code based solution?