# Ubuntu 20.04 as Bluetooth Speaker (A2DP sink) - volume control broken

Tags: sound, bluetooth, volume-control, a2dp

I have been able to pair my iPhone SE (iOS 14.4.2) with my Ubuntu Desktop (20.04) using the default bluetooth settings application and I can play music and this is great but controlling the volume from iOS is not working. When I bring the volume all the way down to silent/mute the Ubuntu Desktop does mute its output but all volume levels above zero result with 100% volume.

Comment: If you are using Pipewire/ Wireplumber instead of PulseAudio, this answer worked for me (on Manjaro): https://www.reddit.com/r/archlinux/comments/yqwnak/disabling_bluetooth_absolute_volume_with_pipewire/

Answer (score 4):

I solved my issue using modifications to the SystemD Bluetooth service proposed by [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/1267874/1355961) on a related question. Specific to Ubuntu 20.04 the SystemD service file has a different path.

Open this file as root: `/etc/systemd/system/bluetooth.target.wants/bluetooth.service`

Change this line: `ExecStart=/usr/lib/bluetooth/bluetoothd`

To this: `ExecStart=/usr/lib/bluetooth/bluetoothd --plugin=a2dp`

Then run these two commands:

```
sudo systemctl daemon-reload  
sudo systemctl restart bluetooth
```