# Can't control bluetooth volume level, only mute or full volume

Tags: sound, bluetooth, volume-control, 22.04

I recently upgraded to 22.04 from 21.10.

And now I can't control volume level for my Bluetooth headset. I can only mute it or it plays at full volume(regardless of the volume selected).

It didn't happen in earlier version.

I can control volume level correctly when playing audio through laptop speakers.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Disable absolute volume in Pulseaudio's config.

Edit the file

```
/etc/pulse/default.pa
```

And change the line

```
load-module module-bluetooth-discover
```

to

```
load-module module-bluetooth-discover avrcp_absolute_volume=false
```

---

Credit for this solution goes to https://www.reddit.com/user/mmstick/
https://www.reddit.com/r/pop_os/comments/s2y0hf/pop_os_2110_brake_bluetooth_device_volume_control/

Comment: Worked for me after `sudo service bluetooth restart`.

Comment: This doesnʼt work for me directly (pipewire not Pulse, because Iʼm not actually on Ubuntu) but it definitely got me started on the right track.  Thanks!

Comment: a slight annoyance i'd like to note is that while this does work on Kubuntu 22.04 controlling the volume via the bluetooth headphones buttons doesn't pop up the volume change overlay, it still changes the volume it's just harder to see at a glance what volume level it's at

Comment: Can I set this separately per device?

Answer (score 0):

I have the same volume level issue while playing anything via bluetooth, but replacing the `load-module module-bluetooth-discover` didn't work for me.

When playing a youtube video (for example), every time that I want to change the volume level, I have to go into the settings and change it on Volume Levels > Chromium (it also happens with Chrome).

[sound settings - browser](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sKEh8.png)

The same happens when using a player like VLC:

[sound settings - VLC player](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6PLaC.png)

System:

- Ubuntu 22.04
- Pulse Audio version: 15.99.1

results from `lspci -v | grep -A7 -i "audio"`:

```
00:1f.3 Audio device: Intel Corporation Cannon Point-LP High Definition Audio Controller (rev 30) (prog-if 80)
    Subsystem: Lenovo Cannon Point-LP High Definition Audio Controller
    Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 32, IRQ 140
    Memory at a4318000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=16K]
    Memory at a4000000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=1M]
    Capabilities: <access denied>
    Kernel driver in use: snd_hda_intel
    Kernel modules: snd_hda_intel, snd_sof_pci_intel_cnl
```

Any ideas on how to fix it?

Comment: This does not really answer the question. If you have a different question, you can ask it by clicking [Ask Question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/ask). To get notified when this question gets new answers, you can [follow this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/345661). Once you have enough [reputation](https://askubuntu.com/help/whats-reputation), you can also [add a bounty](https://askubuntu.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) to draw more attention to this question. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/1241539)

Answer (score 0):

After trying different solutions, this is what worked for me:

1. Open the file `/etc/systemd/system/bluetooth.target.wants/bluetooth.service`
2. Change this line: `ExecStart=/usr/lib/bluetooth/bluetoothd` to `ExecStart=/usr/lib/bluetooth/bluetoothd --plugin=a2dp`
3. Restart the services with `sudo systemctl daemon-reload` and   `sudo systemctl restart bluetooth`

```
Taken from here [1].


  [1]: https://askubuntu.com/a/1350436/1151893
```